# How does PIVOT and UNPIVOT work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm trying to understand the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` commands in T-SQL on SQL Server 2012.  I completely understand what these commands do, but I want to understand a few more details.

Currently I lack in understanding in why when I try to use unpivot I must put the original names of columns of the source table for the pivot command. First I've created a new table and put some data there from another one using pivot command.

```
USE testdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.EmpCustOrders', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.EmpCustOrders;

SELECT empid, A, B,C, D
INTO dbo.EmpCustOrders
FROM (SELECT empid, custid, qty
    FROM dbo.Orders) AS D
PIVOT (SUM(qty) FOR custid IN (A, B, C, D)) As newtable;
```

All ok. Then I try to use `UNPIVOT` command for just creating some table view:

```
USE testdb;
SELECT empid, custid, qty
FROM dbo.EmpCustOrders
UNPIVOT (qty FOR custid IN (A, B, C, D)) AS newTable;
```

Result - this all works perfectly, I can understand why, when I write `SELECT`, I must put names of columns as `custid` and `qty` that are exactly the same as they are in the previous table, but not when I'm writing the `UNPIVOT` on the seperate derived table. How and where is this information stored in the just created table? What part of this am I missing...

For better illustartation of question - add some pic with described situation.

[image]

---

EDIT

[image]

Comment: That screenshot is epic. Nice color choices, too.

Comment: So, you don't understand why you need to put column names to the `UNPIVOT`?. How would SQL Server know the names that it is supposed to use?, there's no way to know that the table you are unpivoting was previously created from another `PIVOT`, so it can't just guess that it should get the column names from the `Orders` table

Comment: @Lamak, but if I use `PIVOT` for filling separate table in database(mean i fill empty table with inforamtion from another one), if then i want to use `UNPIVOT` to just created table (with already added information from PIVOT request but with different column names - you can see this on pic) I must to use columns name from table that was like a sourse for `PIVOT` command? I'm I correct?

Comment: @Kirill You can call those columns in the unpivot whatever you want - they don't have to be the same names.  You can call them `new_qty` or `new_custid` - whatever.

Comment: @bluefeet - no, I can't - please see edit

Comment: @Kirill No, you are not correct. You can name them how you want on the `UNPIVOT`. Again, there's no way for SQL Server to know you created that table from a `PIVOT`, nor is there any reason for it to know

Comment: @Kirill it goes inside the `UNPIVOT` function part and then it will be available in the outside select.  You can use `SELECT empid, custid2, qty2
FROM dbo.EmpCustOrders
UNPIVOT (qty2 FOR custid2 IN (A, B, C, D)) AS newTable`

Comment: @Kirill your edit is showing a wrong code, it should be `UNPIVOT (qty2 FOR custid2 IN ....`

Comment: Ah, now i understand, thanks - i got it, noted

Comment: @Kirill I have to say the way that you are attempting to understand the concepts is part of the problem, typically you don't pivot and then unpivot the same table this way.  Normally, these are separate processes.

Comment: @bluefeet I use for studing some articles from internet - due to this - not all times method that i use for understanding some things is perfect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the same column names but what you are doing is reversing the previous command, in this case the original field names make sense.

```
USE testdb;
SELECT empid, apples, oranges
FROM dbo.EmpCustOrders
UNPIVOT (oranges FOR apples IN (A, B, C, D)) AS newTable;
```

Would work equally as well, but make less sense.